Google Play app and alternative payment method for Russia
I see an app on Google Play from a non-Russian publisher that implements payments through the Google Play Billing Library.
But if the device running the app has a Russian IP, the payment method changes to some Russian merchant accepting Russian cards.
Is this allowed by Google's policy? Or is this cloaking? Within my developer account (Finland), I find the option to add alternative payment systems only for South Korea
